Scipy optimisation doesn't seem to be able to fit correctly
I have two arrays of data, on which I need to fit a nonlinear curve. I am using scipy.optimize and it returns such odd results that when I plot it next to my data points, the curve looks completely wrong. I haven't found anything useful on stackoverflow or youtube and this is my last resort.
I am trying to fit a curve of the shape y = Asin^2(Bx^2 + C/2) on my data points.
My current code looks like this:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

I3 = np.array([12.5, 73.2, 99.5, 96.8, 73.2, 50, 27.1, 10.6, 3.1, 1.31, 0.40, 0.33, 0.41, 0.47, 0.55, 0.56, 0.55, 0.54])
U = np.array([951, 888, 808, 737, 683, 639, 581, 508, 437, 392, 232, 255, 201, 166, 93, 68, 4.5, 3.4])

def fit_func3(x, a, b, c):
    return a * (np.sin(b* x ** 2) + c/2) ** 2

popt, _ = curve_fit(fit_func3, U, I3)
a, b, c = popt

I3_fit = fit_func3(U, a, b, c)


plt.xlabel('Voltage [$\mu$V]')
plt.ylabel('Current [$\mu$A]')
plt.plot(U, I3_fit, color='red', label=f'y = I$_0$ sin$^2$($\pi$BLU$^2$/d$^2$ + C/2)')
plt.scatter(U, I3, color='black', label='podatki')
plt.errorbar(U, I3, xerr=U_err, yerr=I3_err, fmt='o', capsize=5, color='black')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.savefig('graph3.png')
plt.show()

The resulting curve looks like this:

I know that a normal y = sin^2(x^2) looks very close to the data points, but somehow the fitting doesn't work properly. I haven't found any ways to limit the domain so that the data would fit properly.
I even tried to artificially add data points in order to increase the quality of the fit, but it only made it slightly less messy and wild (if this is even helpful to post here):
I3_fill = []
U_fill = []

for i in range(len(I3) - 1):
    I3_fill.extend(np.linspace(I3[i], I3[i+1], 12)[0:-1])
    U_fill.extend(np.linspace(U[i], U[i+1], 12)[0:-1])

I3_fill.append(I3[-1])
U_fill.append(U[-1])

I3_fill = np.array(I3_fill)
U_fill = np.array(U_fill)

I also tried reducing the parameters to only 2 as in y = a * (np.sin(b * x ** 2)) ** 2, but it didn't help at all.
I have tried 2 online fitting tools, and they returned the same result no matter how I tinkered with them.
I am guessing the method scipy uses for optimization is not good in this case?

curve_fit will not work here. Due to the powers of 2, you'd need to horizontally and vertically compress the data before applying an FFT.

@Reinderien How can I do that? I am not sure what you are suggesting. I haven't come across Fast Fourier Transform yet in lectures.

Never mind, I think I figured what you meant and it kinda worked.

Is c on the inside or outside of the sin? You have contradictory expressions.

It being on the inside is as per instructions from the lab. It is supposed to be just a phase shift i  believe

Well, then your fit function is incorrect by that definition

We may question the model which has the generic following form:

Forcing a fit for this model is somehow possible by choosing an appropriate guess:
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, U, I3, p0=[100., 1e-7, 0.])
#(array([ 1.51118541e+02,  2.59631991e-06, -4.73406696e-01]),
# array([[ 4.74332686e+02, -2.01357369e-08, -1.82194008e+00],
#        [-2.01357369e-08,  5.83657181e-15,  1.68952039e-10],
#        [-1.82194008e+00,  1.68952039e-10,  8.38560358e-03]]))

Which leads to a bit more fitness:

But it is clearly not satisfactory. The problem is not curve_fit, it is either your dataset or the model.
The following model better capture the behaviour of your data:
def model(x, a, b, c):
    return a * (np.sin(b * (x - c) ** 2)) ** 2

But this is not perfect at small U:


COMMENT :
a few inspection is of interest before going into heavy calculus.

From inspection it is obvious that a parameter is missing in your equation model. This is certainly the main cause of the bad fitting.
